# emacs 23: struggling to get package.el to work

Tags: emacs

Following the instructions [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA#toc10), I have not had any success. I put [`package.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob_plain;hb=ba08b24186711eaeb3748f3d1f23e2c2d9ed0d09;f=lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el) inside my `~/.emacs.d/` folder.

Inside `.emacs` I put:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda ()
                  (load "~/.emacs.d/my-init.el")))
```

And `myinit.el`:

```
(when
    (load
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/package.el")))

(require 'package)
;; Any add to list for package-archives (to add marmalade or melpa) goes here, e.g.:
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("marmalade" .
      "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("MELPA" .
      "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

I'm not getting any errors when I start emacs. But when I do `M-x package-install [RET] afternoon-theme`, for example, I get a message saying no packages found.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not upgrading Emacs to the most recent stable public release?

Comment: I'm using emacs on scientific linux 6.5, as well as on a server that I ssh into. As far as I know, I can't upgrade either of these versions of emacs. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Have you called `M-x refresh-package-contents` or tried using the `M-x package-list-packages` interface (which performs a refresh, at least in newer versions).

Comment: I get `[No match]` for both of those.

Comment: That's odd. I can see that `package-list-packages` is defined (as an alias for `list-packages` in the Emacs 23 version of package.el that you've linked to). OTOH I transposed words in (what should have been) `M-x package-refresh-contents`, so that one was misleading (apologies).